# how to output multiple files in 1 stored procedure via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working in SQL Server 2008 and BIDS.  Due to some performance problems, I am re-designing my current architecture.  Currently, I have a stored procedure that has many INSERT INTO SELECT statements inside of it.  In my new architecture, I am trying to get the performance of SSIS for inserts (instead of INSERT INTO in SSMS).  So, my new stored proc will still have all of the SELECT statements (just no INSERT INTO before each of them).  I will call this stored proc in SSIS (with a few parameters supplied that are needed by the SELECTs).  My goal is to have each SELECT write to separate flat files.  (Actually, certain groups of SELECTS will write to separate flat files, such that I have just a few -- instead of a billion -- flat file connection managers.)  I know how to execute a stored proc in SISS and have it write a multiple-row set to a flat file.  But, is it possible to have the execution of 1 stored proc in SSIS to write several multiple-row sets to several flat files?  If so, how can it be done?

Comment: If improved performance is your primary goal, you will be better off doing the selects separately, making each one the source of its own dataflow.   That way you have parallel processing.   But if centralizing your code is more important than performance, there might be some ways.

Comment: Making each SELECT the source of its own dataflow will be too costly in development time, as I have ~500 SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Data Flow for Dynamic Export is not possible due to Strict Metadata Architecture of SSIS. But you can do it using Control Flow task. You have to write [BCP command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) in Execute Process Task and call it for each table you want to export.

**Steps:**

1. Call `select * from information_schema.tables` and grab result set into variable
2. Use foreach Loop task to loop through tables
3. Use execute process task to call BCP in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one stored proc write to as many files as you want. Please look at this article by Phil Factor, https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

However you are loosing all the power of SSIS - such as redirection on error rows, logging, parrallel processing. What you need to do sounds like a perfect SSIS task (or series of tasks).